# remove all signs and marks in the a string except the apostrophe mark

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove all signs and marks in the `reference` except the apostrophe mark.

So here is what I have so far:

```js
let reference = "I was; sent* to? Earth,* to protect you. he's car: is! red."


let refered = reference.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
console.log(refered);
```

The problem is I can't make an exception for apostrophe mark and it'll be removed from the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by escaping the apostrophe in your expression (you escape it by typing `\'`):

```js
let reference = "I was; sent* to? Earth,* to protect you. he's car: is! red."


let refered = reference.replace(/[^\w\s\']/gi, '');
console.log(refered); // I was sent to Earth to protect you he's car is red
```

`[^\w\s\']` means everything that isn't a word (`\w`), a space (`\s`) or an apostrophe (`\'`).